# NSColorPanel's selector has been called twice

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nscolorpanel

I have shared instance of NSColorPanel and I set selector to him. I use it for background color and for font color. When I want to set text color everything works fine, but when I want to set background color then selector is called twice and background color has been changed to previous color. There is some code:

```
- (IBAction)showColorPanel:(id)sender {
NSColorPanel *panel = [NSColorPanel sharedColorPanel];
[panel orderFront:nil];
//[panel ]
[panel setAction:@selector(changeColorForBackground:)];
[panel setTarget:self];
[panel makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
isFontPanel = NO;
[[self getDesktopController] setFirstString];
}
```

Selector:

```
- (void)changeColorForBackground:(id)sender {
if (!isFontPanel) {
    DesktopController *desktopController = [self getDesktopController];
    [desktopController updateCellBackgroundColor:[sender color]];
}
}
```

Thx for reply!

Comment: Do you have your own color wells, or are you using the text color and background color wells in the font panel? If you're doing the latter, why are you setting yourself as the color panel's target?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added NSWindowDelegate to my controller and add method

```
- (void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification {
    if ([notification.object isEqual:[NSColorPanel sharedColorPanel]]) {
        [[NSColorPanel sharedColorPanel] setAction:nil];
    }
}
```

So I have to close NSColorPanel before I use it again.

Comment: Very ugly. Expect lots of complaints/negative reviews from your users about the color panel not working. And they won't be wrong—this behavior is broken.